# После смены класса елемента продолжает отрабатывать старые обработчик событий

Tags: jquery, классы, click

Обработчики событий:

```
$(document).on('click','.old-class', function () {
    --\--
}

$(document).on('click','.new-class', function () {
    --\--
    }

<input class="old-class">
```

Меняю класс в елементе:

```
$('input').removeClass('old-class');

$('input').addClass('new-class');
```

в DOM елемент отображается с новым классом `:input class="new-class"`, но на него продолжает реагировать обработчик события для класса `old-class`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Что-то не договаривается в вопросе. Проверил - обработчик old-class перестал работать.

Comment: Возможно вы правы. Но решил проблему удалением старого input, и созданием нового с другим классом. Input type="file", обработчик слушал изменения и делал предпросмотр. Может из за этого.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде-примере есть синтаксические ошибки. Не хватает закрывающих скобок.

Посмотрите реализованный пример
[CodePen клик](https://codepen.io/bookamba/pen/BaLVxqZ?editors=0001)

JS:

```
$(document).on('click','.old-class', function () {
    console.log("old-class");
});

$(document).on('click','.new-class', function () {
    console.log("new-class");
    });

$("#btn").click(function() {
  $('input').removeClass('old-class');

$('input').addClass('new-class');
});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="old-class">
<button id="btn">Remove old-class</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо.) Но проблема ни в этом. Код-пример я писал навскидку, только передавая смысл. В проекте все скобки на месте. В противном случае браузер бы сигнализировал об ошибке. Да и PhpStorm не пропустил бы такой косяк.)) Но вам плюс за внимательность.)